# How to show current time in magento admin panel?

Tags: magento

I'd like to show current system time in mangeto admin panel at the top.

[image]

I tried to find the code and I found this line:

```
<?php echo $this->formatDate(null, 'full') ?>
```

in

> app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\page\header.php

But I don't know how to change it.

I've seen that there is a different time for mangento. see [post](http://magentocookbook.wordpress.com/2010/02/15/magento-date-time/).

Comment: i've problem in modifying this line `<?php echo $this->formatDate(null, 'full') ?>`

Comment: found file `app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\page\header.php`

Comment: Then, please update the post and include relevant code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I was expecting:

```
<?php echo date("m/d/Y h:i:s a", Mage::getModel('core/date')->timestamp(time())); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Magento has function  `Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('Y-m-d H:i:s')`

Answer (score 0):

< ?php echo $this->formatDate(null, 'full',true ) ?>

You can pass 3rd parameter true for show time.